# Mongodb - Return all the associative documents with value for the key derived from another query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, database

I have a document of following structure:

```
{
    "Type" : "Request",
    "Cat" : "A",
    "ID" : 10
}

{
    "Type" : "Processed",
    "Cat" : "A",
    "ID" : 10
}

{
    "Type" : "Receieved",
    "Cat" : "A",
    "ID" : 10
}

{
    "Type" : "Receieved",
    "Cat" : "B",
    "ID" : 11
}

{
    "Type" : "Processed",
    "Cat" : "C",
    "ID" : 12
}
```

I want documents:

1. Those documents with Type: "Processed" and get its ID
2. And all the associated documents with the ID got from above (1st step).

I need the results to be like this:

```
{
    "Type" : "Request"
    "Cat" : "A"
    "ID" : 10
}

{
    "Type" : "Processed"
    "Cat" : "A"
    "ID" : 10
}

{
    "Type" : "Receieved"
    "Cat" : "A"
    "ID" : 10
}

{
    "Type" : "Processed"
    "Cat" : "C"
    "ID" : 12
}
```

Can someone help me on how to achieve this ? I used elemmatch under $match in aggregate - but its not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     {$project : {
           "ID":1,
            "doc.Type" : "$Type",
            "doc.Cat" :  "$Cat",
            "doc.ID" :   "$ID"
        }
     }
     {$group : {
           _id : "$ID",
           docs : {$push : doc}
        }
     },
     {$match : {
           "docs.Type":"Processed"
        }      
     },
     {$unwind : "$docs"},
     {$project : {
           _id : 0,
           docs : 0,
           "Type" : "$docs.Type",
           "Cat" : "$docs.Cat",
           "ID" : "$docs.ID"
        }
     }
])
```